# How can I append the one SVG (graph) inside another SVG node (rect) after onclick using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I want to populate the data inside the parent graph node, that is I want to add nested svg on click event using d3.js.
I have tried following code but the output is looking very different I want to show the graph inside the after on click event of first svg node.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 600)
                        .attr("height", 400)
                        svg.append('rect')
                            .attr('class', 'content shape')
                            .attr("width", 20)
                            .attr("height", 20)
                            .attr("stroke", "black")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                            .style("fill", function (d) {
                                return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                            })
                            .on("click", createMap);

    var createMap (mapData){
        if(mapdata.data){
            d3.select(this).attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 200)
                .call(function(d){
                    var nodeMap = getGeneratedmap(mapdata.data);
                    return nodeMap
                }
        }
    }

    var getGeneratedmap(mapdata){
        var generatedmapSVG = d3.select("#subnodeMap").append("svg")
        ....
        ....(logic for map generation)
        ....
        return generatedmapSvg
    }

    <body>
        <div id="mainMap">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
        <div id="subnodeMap"></div>
    </body>
```

Please guide me and give the proper way to solve the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Your first SVG, the var `svg` is being appended to `<body>`. The second SVG is being appended to the div with ID `#subnodemap`, so you are not actually nesting the first SVG inside the second. You probably want to do something like:

```
var generatedmapSVG = svg.append("svg")
```

That's about as much as I can help you without a working example in Codepen or similar, hope it gets you towards a solution.